# Kotlin - Override/Implement array-like accessor function

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to override or implement the `[]` accessors in Kotlin (using operator overloading or similar)?

```
val testObject = MyCustumObject()
println(testObject["hi"])  // i.e. implement this accessor.
```

In Python this is possible by implementing `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Kotlin, it is [`get` and `set` operator functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator) that you need to implement:

```
class C {
    operator fun get(s: String, x: Int) = s + x
    operator fun set(x: Int, y: Int, value: String) {
        println("Putting $value at [$x, $y]")
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
val c = C()
val a = c["123", 4] // "1234"
c[1, 2] = "abc" // Putting abc at [1, 2]
```

You can define `get` and `set` with arbitrary number of parameters for *indices* (at least one, of course); in addition, `set` has the expression which is assigned at the use site passed as its last argument:

- `a[i_1, ..., i_n]` is translated to `a.get(i_1, ..., i_n)`
- `a[i_1, ..., i_n] = b` is translated to `a.set(i_1, ..., i_n, b)`

`get` and `set` can have different overloads as well, for example:

```
class MyOrderedMap<K, V> {
    // ...

    operator fun get(index: Int): Pair<K, V> = ... // i-th added mapping
    operator fun get(key: K): V = ... // value by key
}
```

<sup>Note: this example introduces undesirable ambiguity for `MyOrderedMap<Int, SomeType>` since both `get` functions will match calls like `m[1]`.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) the `a[i]` is translated to `a.get(i)`. In example:

```
class MyObject {
    operator fun get(ix:Int):String{
        return "hello $ix"
    }
}
```

Let's you write:

```
val a = MyObject()
println(a[123]) //-> "hello 123"
```

Similarly `a[i] = b` is translated to a method call `a.set(i, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override get().

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

```
a[i] translates to a.get(i)
```